# Which version of php is compatible with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework

I used `zf 1.11.11` with `php 5.3.3` on a CentOS 6.x . Now i installed a new clean CentOS 7 but i can't matching `php` version with my old code. I can not find a repository which contains `php 5.3.3` and proper `Apache Server` that works with my code. Also i don't know `zf 1.11.11` can work with which version of `php`.

How can i find the proper Repository which works with `yum` and install appropriate php and apache for my `zf` application?

Comment: What isn't working with your code?

Comment: Distrowatch suggests Centos 7 comes with Php 5.4.16.  I'd have thought that would most likely work.  Rob Allen suggests a ZF1 project of his worked on Php7 with minor adjustment (he had to update third party code). https://akrabat.com/testing-my-zf1-app-on-php7/

Comment: From ZF 1.11 manual (ZF requirements): Zend recommends the most current release of PHP for critical security and performance enhancements, and currently supports PHP 5.2.4 or later.

Comment: @Progrock : moslty Views does not render perfectly

Answer (score 1):

According to the [composer.json of the framework](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zendframework/zendframework/master/composer.json) PHP 5.6 or 7.0 is required.

To install it on CentOS 6.0 you can add the following repositoy information (according to https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/):

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

After that is added, run `yum install php70w php70w-opcache` as stated in the link above

### Edit

As stated in the comments, I've misread the version number for the zend framework installation. The suggested PHP-version as pointed out by @Progrock the required PHP-version for Zend Framework 1.12 as defined in the [composer.json](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/composer.json) is >=5.2.11

You can for example follow [this guide](http://community.webcorecloud.com/tutorials/compiling_php_5217_on_centos_6/) to install php 5.2.17 on CentOS from museum.php.net, but I'd recommend installing one of the [currently supported versions of PHP](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: This isn't pertinent for ZF1 projects.

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendframework1,  Composer file: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/composer.json suggests Php >=5.2.11 for ZF 1.12.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I misread the version number. I'll update my answer.